# What is the purpose of alignment in Xcode image attribute inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I was fixing a problem related to image aspect ratio so just discovered the alignment property in attribute inspector but don't understand it's purpose even after searching from the internet.

Any help regarding this alignment property will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is identical to the UIImage's [`alignmentRectInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624139-alignmentrectinsets) property (which you would set in code by calling `withAlignmentRectInsets(_:)`). This is useful because a UIImageView automatically acquires its image's `alignmentRectInsets` (under autolayout) and so you can position/size the image view with respect to the "edges" of its visible image rather then the actual boundaries of the view.

Comment: Working example in this downloadable demo project: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch02p057imageRendering